# How to pass a list to a function in R?

Tags: function, r

I have been having difficulty finding information about how to pass a list to a function in R.

I have used this approach before, e.g.

```
plot(list(x=1,y=1))
```

but the following example gives me an error:

```
foo <- function(a, b) c <- a + b
foo(list(a=1,b=1))

Error in foo(list(a = 1, b = 1)) : 
   argument "b" is missing, with no default
```

Furthermore, `?function` doesn't work and `help('function')` does not provide information on passing a list to a function.

**update**

To clarify, I understand how I can use a list as a single argument, but I was confused because I was under the impression that a property of functions was that multiple arguments could be passed as a list. It appears that this impression was incorrect. Rather, many functions are written specifically to handle lists, as described in the comments and answers below.

Comment: You are passing a single argument to your function which expects 2. The correct call would be: foo(a=list(1), b=list(2)). If you wanted to pass to your function a single list then you have to declare it as function(a) and then call it the same way you did. Your function logic is also off since you can't add non-numeric arguments in such a way and you will have to index your lists within your function body to achieve what you want (guessing here) i.e. a[[1]] + b[[1]].

Comment: I haven't looked into it, but I would guess that `plot` has a method that handles lists.  To do something similar with `foo`, you would need to make it generic and write appropriate methods.

Comment: @Joshua, thank you for the clarification. I was under the impression that a list could be passed without special handling.

Comment: `plot(list(x=1,y=1))` calls `plot.default`, which uses `xy.coords`.  The source of `xy.coords` has an if/else branch to handle multiple types of `x` arguments (`ts`, `matrix`, `data.frame`, `formula`, `complex`, `list`).  So it's not a generic using methods.  The analogous solution would be to define `foo(a, b=NULL)` and have an if/else branch when `b` is null to handle multiple classes of `a`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use do.call

```
foo <- function(a, b)  a + b

do.call(foo, list(a=1,b=1))
```

Alternatively you can do

```
foo <- function(l) l$a + l$b

foo(list(a=1,b=1))
```

Answer (score 7):

Your function has two arguments but you are only passing one, hence the error.

You can modify your code like so:

```
foo <- function(a) c <- a[[1]] + a[[2]]
foo(list(a=1,b=1))
```